# Clarification on MySQL 5.6 using IN PLACE alter table for adding/dropping the same index

Tags: mysql, performance

From the docs:

> An ALTER TABLE statement that contains DROP INDEX and ADD INDEX
>   clauses that both name the same index uses a table copy, not Fast
>   Index Creation.

This is a bit unclear to me. Is it talking about the NAME of the index? Can someone give an example of a query in which MySQL resorts to a table copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it sounds like this line is about:

- An (One, single) ALTER TABLE statement
- that contains (both) a DROP INDEX and an ADD INDEX clause
- and both clauses name the same index

and states that such a statement uses a table copy, not Fast Index Creation.

Such a statement would be:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
  DROP INDEX MyIndex
  ADD INDEX MyIndex(MyColumn);
```

The documentation is not really clear about the reason behind this, but I think the database want to create an index first and then drop the other index, so the statement by itself can more easily be made atomic. (Creating the index might fail.) If the index name itself is used in the storage as well, that order of first creating then dropping would give a conflict.

After all, fast index creation is a relatively new feature, so they might improve this over time.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I wasn't even aware you could combine them in the first place. So it's regarding the NAME of the index? If I had an index `myindex` that indexed column `my_id`, would the following query use a table copy? `alter table mytable drop index myindex add index anotherindex(my_id, anothercolumn);`?